# Add a background or not depending on angularjs condition using ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add a background url style depending on a condition, so I attemped using data-ng-style but couldn't make it work for some reason, i don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
data-ng-style="true : {'background-image': 'url(' + getThumbnailUrl(item) + ')'}, false : {}[item.thumbnailClass === undefined]"
```

Basically, what I want to do is, if thumbnailClass is undefined, set the background-image as data-ng-style, otherwise, do nothing.

Adding JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5666/
Imagine even that fafa is boolean, if true apply the style, if false, dont do anything.

How can I achieve this in AngularJS ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is just a bit off. This should work.

```
data-ng-style="{'background-image': (item.thumbnailClass === undefined) ? 'url(' + getThumbnailUrl(item) + ')' : ''}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using `ng-class`. Maybe you could try something like this:

In your CSS

```
.bgImage {
    background-image: url('someImage.jpg');
}
```

In your HTML tag (I used div as an example):

```
<div ng-class="{bgImage: thumbnailClass !== undefined}">
   <h3> Something </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: thing is the URL is dynamic.. i iterate through an array with ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you post a simple JSFiddle of your code? Would make it easier to understand on my end.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5666/  Imagine that fafa is boolean, not even undefined, how do i manage to apply the bg if fafa is true, and not apply the style if false?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in the controller

```
if(yourcondtion){
  $scope.myStyle = {
    "background-color" : "coral",
  };
} else {
   $scope.myStyle = {};
}
```

In your HTML you can put ng-style="myStyle"